# Possible to plot subset of column based on unique value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[*edited 10/22/19 for clarity*]

I'm in the process of learning how to use Pandas.  I have a large data set that I would like to plot (line plot) in various ways.  Here's a mock example, with columns `Date`, `Sample Location`, `Test1`, `Test2`, `Test3` (integer):

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Generate some data; covert dict to dataframe
MyDates = list(repeat(['1/1/19', '2/1/19', '3/1/19', '4/1/19', '5/1/19'], 5))
# repeat won't work if run from text editor
SampleSites = ['Site 1', 'Site 2', 'Site 3', 'Site 4', 'Site 5'] * 5
Test1 = list(randint(0, 10, 25))
Test2 = list(randint(0, 10, 25))
Test3 = list(randint(0, 10, 25))
MyData = {'Date': MyDates, 'Sample Location': SampleSites, 'Test 1': Test1, 'Test 2': Test2, 'Test 3': Test3}
DF1 = pd.DataFrame(MyData)
# Sometimes this doesn't work; not sure why.
```

Every thing I've seen in regards to plotting Pandas data frames involves using slicing and methods such as `pivot_table` and `groupby` to organize the data in such a way that it can be plotted as desired.  See the following example:

```
# General approach that I have seen others do, I would like a more concise way if possible:

# Plot "Test 1" results for all Sample Locations
DF2 = DF1.drop(labels = ['Test 2', 'Test 3'], axis = 1)
DF3 = DF2.pivot_table(index = 'Date', columns = 'Sample Location')
DF3.plot()

# Plot columns Test 1, Test 2, and Test 3 for Sample Location 'Site 1'
# Select subset of data from DF1 to plot
FilterSamples = ['Site 1']
# Slice data frame down to desired type
DF2 = DF1[DF1['Sample Location'].isin(FilterSamples)]
DF3 = DF2.reset_index(drop = True)
DF3.plot(x = 'Date', y = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3'])
```

This approach seems cumbersome as it seems to require several objects to be passed to get to where the data needs to be for plotting.

It would be great if I could have a concise way to plot from a large data frame, where x and y values can be filtered per adjacent values in the row.  For example, instead of filtering the data frame to only include Sample Location 'Site 1', it would be great if I could write something like the following:

```
# pseudo-code example of what I would like to do:
# Only plots x values (date) of rows with Site 1 value in Sample Location column
# Only plots corresponding y values for column Test 1
DF1.plot (x = DF1.Date[DF1.Sample Location['Site 1']], y = DF1.Test1)

# Is something like this possible?
```

Hopefully the the question is more clear now.  Any suggestions/criticisms regarding the primary question or any aspect of my code will be appreciated!

Comment: Please edit your question to be clearer. a) When you say *"plot specific values (within a column) against their corresponding values in another column"*, it's less vague if you give an example, but anyway you seem to mean *"filter rows where `Color`.eq('green')"*. b) But when you say *"do multiple plots and layer them"* (those are called ***subplots***), then you really mean *"iterate over rows/group by `Color`, plot each row(/group) individually"*. I think that's what you're looking for? Please edit your question.

Comment: So, you wanted to ask *"How do I group-by color, and plot each point on  separate subplot?"*. But you don't even need to do subplots, since `plot` will directly accept a text value of a color name from `Color`. You could just use `df.apply(lambda row: ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestions.  When I said _"do multiple plots and layer them"_ , I didn't mean subplots, I meant have multiple series.  So, in my example, that would mean plotting green, blue, and red as individual series.

Answer (score 1):

To plot multiple layers in one graph you can use directly pyplot from matplotlib:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.plot(df.columnA,df.columnB,color='red')
plt.plot(df.columnA,df.columnC,color='blue')

plt.legend(["ColumnB","ColumnC"])

plt.show()
```

You can play easily with the axis, colors and graoh design this way.
You can also operate directly without generating a new dataframe directly such as : 
`plt.plot(df.columnA,df.columnA-df.columnB)` for example

Comment: Sorry...```color = 'red'``` would just make the line plot line the color red correct?  I'm actually looking to plot "color" (which is just a dummy column of categories I used for mock data example) as individual series.  Probably not the best choice on my part for example data.

Comment: Yes that is correct. I don't understand what you mean by 'individual series'